# sudo pip <something> doesn't work but pip <something> works

Tags: pip, sudo

Just like the title says, when I try to:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

I get an error:

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

If I remove the `sudo` everything goes fine - why is that?

Comment: pip must have been installed for the given user account.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy can I undo the `pip` install and install it for root?

Comment: You can follow the answer by @JohnDoe if on Linux. If on Windows, just re-run the installer with the `for all Users` option checked. That should help.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom If my answer was useful, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `pip` is not installed at system level.
You can install `pip` at system level by running `sudo apt-get install python-pip` from terminal.
After this you can upgrade pip by running `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` and `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`.

Not wanting to use `sudo` for installing python packages and no need for global package installs you can use the `--user` flag like this :

`pip install --user <packagename>`